# Endomorphism rings of infinitely generated free modules generated by idempotents?

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, noncommutative-rings

Let $M$ be a free right $R$-module. When $M_R\cong R_R^n$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$, then we know that the endomorphism ring $E={\rm End}(M_R)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{M}_n(R)$. We also know that $\mathbb{M}_{n}(R)$ is generated as a ring by its idempotents, when $n\geq 2$.  Is $E$ generated by its idempotents if $M_R$ is not finitely generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's true: every element can be written as $tu+vw+x+y-4z$ with each of $t,\dots, z$ idempotent.

More generally, this holds for an arbitrary module $M$ that is isomorphic to $N\times N$ for some module $N$.

Indeed, in this setting, every endomorphism of $M$ can be written as block matrix $\begin{pmatrix} A & B\\ C & D\end{pmatrix}$. Then

$$\begin{pmatrix} A & B\\ C & D\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} I & A\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I & 0\\I & 0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ D & I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & I\\ 0 & I\end{pmatrix}$$
$$+\begin{pmatrix} I & B\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ C & I\end{pmatrix}-4\begin{pmatrix} I & 0\\ 0 & I\end{pmatrix}.$$

(Although unnecessary to the question, the proof can be adapted to $M$ that is isomorphic to the $n$-power of a given module for $n\ge 2$, with a different writing.)

Comment: Of course!  In other words, when $M\cong N\times N$, then ${\rm End}(M)\cong \mathbb{M}_2({\rm End}(N))$.  Great observation.

Comment: Blast, I spent a long time editing, improving this to any module of the form $M^2\oplus N^3$ (which uniformly covers all modules $P^n$ for $n\ge 3$, and hence all ultraproducts of such endomorphism algebras)... and when I refreshed the page after the other answer was deleted, all has disappeared. The argument is not hard but it takes time to write down all these matrices... So well, let's stick to have it as a remark.

Comment: i think it must be true for any cardinal $\kappa$ such that $M= R^{\kappa}$

Comment: @Cary yes, this is covered by my answer (at least when $\kappa$ is infinite, assuming ZFC, or finite even)

Comment: Thank you so much @Ycor

Comment: @YCor I was thinking about the subring generated bu idempotents of $Zp$, where $Zp$ is the ring of p-adic integers. and I said: let $S$ be the subring generated by idempotents of $Zp$. As 1 belongs to S and S closed under addition so every prime $p$ belongs to $S$. Also since $S$ closed under multiplication for every positive integer$ n$, $p^n$ belongs to $S$. so every linear combination of  $p^n$ belongs to $S$ which implies that $S$ equals to $ Zp$. But my friend said  $S$ equal to $\mathbb{Z}$. which one is the correct answer?

Comment: Yes the subring generated by idempotents is reduced to $\mathbf{Z}$. A subring doesn't have to be closed under "linear combination". This would be an ideal. In every unital ring the ideal generated by idempotents is the whole ring.

Comment: @YCor yes it doesn't have to be closed  under linear combination but in our case since $1$ belongs to $S$ so  $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq S$ and hence for every $a_{k}\in \mathbb{Z}$ , $\sum _{k\geq 0}a_{k}p^{n}$ belongs to $S$.

Comment: You assume stability under infinite sums, which is not automatic for a subring (but is for a closed subring).

Comment: @YCor yes but how can i find this subring is not  a closed subring. in fact I haven't heard about it before

Comment: @YCor, Shouldn't we replace  $ \space 2\begin{pmatrix} I & 0\\ 0 & I\end{pmatrix} $ in your answer? i think we have to subtract $2I$.